# I can't find out why my application on my phone is close/destroy when open a new app or moving to new opened app window?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-studio

It's not that i'm getting exception or error or a message my app is crashed.
It's just i see my app swap down and get closed.

This is my MainActivity code a bit long but maybe something there make it i'm not sure.
Other then that i don't think it's ram memory problem since i can close and open other apps on my phone like games and others.

I don't think it's anything to do with life cycle or that i need to save and restore. If i'm not wrong the app lshould be automatic live and keep running even if i moved for a second to whatsapp or to a game and then i want to get back to my app it should be in the top of my phone so i can roll it and click on it's icon and back to it.

But in this case i don't see my app at the top and if i click on it it will run it over again.

My device is lg g3.

```
package com.test.webservertest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.AndroidRuntimeException;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";
    private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
        "http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=nothing",
        "http://10.0.0.7:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
    private String iptouse = "";
    private TextView text;
    private boolean connectedtoipsuccess = false;
    private int counter = 0;
    private Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
        addListenerOnButton();
        currentActivity = this;
        initTTS();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {
                                counter = i;
                                try
                                {
                                    response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    String err = e.toString();
                                }

                                if (response!=null)
                                {


                                    try
                                    {
                                        final String a = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                text.setText(a + " Oמ " + ipaddresses[counter]);
                                            }
                                        });

                                        iptouse = ipaddresses[i].substring(0, 26);
                                        connectedtoipsuccess = true;
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                    }

                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                    break;

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }





                        }
                        counter = 0;
                        if (response == null)
                        {
                            text.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch onStart() to all fragments.  Ensure any created loaders are
     * now started.
     */

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        TextToSpeechServer.main(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void initTTS() {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                mTts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new OnInitListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int i) {

                        if(i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE
                                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                                mTts.setPitch(1);
                                mTts.speak(textforthespeacch, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String textforthespeacch = "";
    public static void TextToSpeak(String text) {
        textforthespeacch = text;
    }

    private boolean is_start = true;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float lastdownx = 0;
            float lastdowny = 0;

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    lastdownx = eventX;
                    lastdowny = eventY;

                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            byte[] response = null;
                            if (connectedtoipsuccess == true)
                            {
                                if (is_start == true)
                                {
                                    response = Get(iptouse + "start");
                                    is_start = false;
                                } else
                                {
                                    response = Get(iptouse + "stop");
                                    is_start = true;
                                }
                                if (response != null)
                                {
                                    String a = null;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        a = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                                        textforthespeacch = a;
                                        MainActivity.currentActivity.initTTS();
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                   
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;
        String urlStr = urlIn;
        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);
            byte[] bufOut;
            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }
            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you switching to another App? It you press Back, your App will close. If you press Home, your app will be put into the background and can be resumed via the normal Android app switcher.

Comment: I have on my lg g3 on the botton something like left arrow i assume that's back and the app is quiting.  Then in the middle i have a circle that bring me to the main screen of my android device but also on this i don't see my app on the top it's quiting also. I also tried for example running a game like backgammon live and even if i'm doing the left arrow or the circle and i click on the game icon it's resuming it not starting it over again.

Comment: Same for wahtsapp . I don't know how the backgammon live is working now i can't shut down the app doing this left arrow or the circle keep the app running. But what's im saying that in my app edither doing <| or O in both cases i see my app scrolling down to bottom and shut down closed.